# How to position element to the right?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 buttons in the end of the form.
I am using styled components and react. 
Problem is that when the left aligned button is being hidden, the other button which is supposed to stay in the right, comes to the left. Below is my css(and screenshot of layout), what do i need to add/change?

```
const ButtonsContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
`;
```

meanwhile the code on the jsx part

```
      <div>
        <ButtonsContainer>
          {tabIndex != 0 && (
              <Button
                label=" Go Back"               
              />
          )}
          {nextStep > 0 && (
              <Button                  
                label=" Next Step"
              />
          )}
        </ButtonsContainer>
      </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Use `float` css attribute. Search about it and use it.

Comment: Give right item `margin-left: auto`

Answer (score 2):

You could have 2 flex container, one for the left button, the other for the right button:

(css only)

```css
.buttons-container {
   display: flex;
}

.button-left {
   flex: 0 0 50%;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-start;
}

.button-right {
   flex: 0 0 50%;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons-container">
   <div class="button-left"><button></button></div>
   <div class="button-right"><button></button></div>
</div>
```

Sorry, I don't know styled-components, but you get the idea I am sure.

There are other tricks, you should put some time to study flexbox.

Comment: almost worked :p when right button is alone, now it is being displayed on the center.

Comment: Could you shave the code of the button divs and the javascript that hides the left button?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply align the right button to right using text-align, the left button will stay always left because it's the default alignement for inline elements. In the suggestion below i'm using a div as a row, and two divs inside with 50% max-width.

```css
.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col-50 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-50">
    <button>
      Go Back
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-50 text-right">
    <button>
      Next Step
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `display: none` to hide the element? If so you should probably switch to using `visibility: hidden`.

`display: none` removes the element from the page totally, whereas `visibility: hidden` will hide the element but also preserve the space it was taking up.

Comment: no, i am just using ternary operation of React to not show div when x condition is true

Comment: Ah, so instead of removing the div entirely you could maybe add an inline style... something like this: `style={(CONDITION) ? {visibility: 'hidden'} : {visibility: 'visible'}}`